# I want to connect my iPod using the headset jack to a portable PA system and am worried about phantom power

Tags: audio, xlr

I have a Liberty 4500 portable PA system and a headset plug to male XLR adapter.

I am afraid the phantom power from the Liberty PA system will fry my iPod.

How can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like the [Liberty 4500](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001UI3OFY) has two XLRs with Phantom power and one 1/4" line in.

The 1/4" line in is the one you want to use for the iPod, as it does not have phantom power.

You will need a cable with a 3.5mm stereo male connector on one end and a 1/4" mono male connector on the other.  The closest I could find were a [3.5mm stereo male to two male RCA connectors cable](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/24-9490&t=1) and a [two female RCA to 1/4" mono male adapter](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/27-4195&t=1).

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the 1/4" input, because it won't have phantom power.

An adapter from iPod (or other 3.5mm device: smartphone, CD player, computer…) to 1/4" [will run you about $4](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?cid=836335013125120276).

If you have the manual for the Liberty 4500 (I can't find one on Google), see if it supports disabling phantom power on one or all of the XLR inputs.